# Multisites with different root directory

Tags: multisite, directory, multi-language

I have an html static site with multiple languages (i'm using subdirectory strategy), which looks like this:

> domain.com/br/

And I have a WP installation at

> domain.com/br/blog/

I'm planning  to turn my WP to multilanguage and I need to know if it's possible to use one single WP Core Installation and deal each language as a different site.

I need that

> domain.com/br/blog

and

> domain.com/us/blog

be the same WP installation. Is that possible?
Should I install one WP Core in /us/blog/ and /br/blog/?
If so, how can I deal with multilanguage options?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, this is possible with the Multisite feature of WordPress. As hint for a Multilingual solution as addon, see the [MultilingualPress](https://multilingualpress.org) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as if you have one website and you want each 'site' to have the same content but just in its own language at its own URL.

You can achieve this via one core installation and a multilanguage plugin (I've used QTranslate with some success).

Unless you want to maintain separate sets of structures, you don't need to turn on the multisite features (or have more than one installation).

Bear in mind that you might need to do some clever redirection if you want there to be more than one path to a language (e.g. /us and /uk would both be English).

Comment: I need to be able to create exclusive content to each language, but all the structure will be the same.

Comment: OK - so if the structure is identical (as in for every single page, there's a version in every language), you could use the approach I describe above.  If you have some pages or content that only exist in some languages, it would make sense to create separate sites using a multisite install.  This would also mean you don't need to use an internationalisation / translation plugin (unless you wanted to for specific sites - e.g. French and English for Canada, in which case you could install the plugin just for that site).

Comment: I meant to add - I took exactly this approach for a set of similar-but-not-identical sites a few years ago and it worked well.

Comment: I'm reading some stuff of qTranslate and I think it's right what I need. Thank your for your tips.
And be prepared, maybe I need some extra help ;)

Comment: qTranslate means you basically have an extra post content tab for each language you add. You can put whatever you like into it (that is, it doesn't try and translate it automatically, so you could say something different in each language).  Good luck!